# Cache static table in memory SQL Server CE 3.5?

Tags: .net, sql-server-ce

I'm working on a windows mobile 6.5 app and my .NET is not that great yet. I have a table in my database that is very rarely updated and is used in joins with other throughout the app. The performance is not good enough. The device has more than enough memory to store the whole table, so I was wondering whether I could make the SQL Server CE store the table in RAM and get an instant speed up throughout?

I would deal with updates to this table separately as it's only done in one place and rarely.

Or is there a better solution?

I could just bash out a hash table and change all my queries to use it instead, but was wondering whether there was a lazier/more elegant way of doing it.

Comment: Have you checked that you have the required indexes?

Comment: Yep, I'm joining only on the primary key.